# NodeJS working on Localhost but not working online

Tags: mysql, node.js, ejs

I'm practicing NodeJS and trying to upload a landing page via FTP but it's not working online. Does anyone know if we have to do a special config for uploading the website to the web?

In my localhost it's working perfectly. The problem comes when it goes online.

It just shows:

```
Index of /landing

[ICO]   Name    Last modified   Size    Description
```

If I navigate to the path EX.: 'website.com/views/index.ejs', the file is there but with no style or script.

I'm calling this on the ejs file under views:

```
<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kanit" rel="stylesheet"> 
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="/server.js"></script>
```

I'm sure i'm missing something but can't find out how.

this is my code on server.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs'); //extension of views
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/css'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/js'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/img'));


//mysql 
var mysql = require('mysql');
var pool = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit : 100, //focus it
    host : 'mydb',
    user : 'mydb',
    password : 'mydb',
    database : 'mydb'


});

//opening view

app.get('/', function(req,res){
    res.render('index');
});

//insert data 
app.post('/insert', function(req,res){

   pool.getConnection(function(error,conn){

       var queryString = "insert into leads(email,name) values('"+req.body.femail+"','"+req.body.fname+"')";

       conn.query(queryString,function(error,results){
           if(error)
               {
                   throw error;
               }
           else 
               {
                 res.send('Inserted Successfully!')
               }

       });
       conn.release();
   });


});


//start server

var server = app.listen(8000, function () {

  var host = server.address().address
  var port = server.address().port

  console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port);

});
```

If anyone can help I wold be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

i'm pretty sure your node app is not running, you'll need a server that capable running nodejs apps, not sure if ftp could work, but i usually use VPS. once you get the server:

1. Install git
2. Install node
3. Pull your code

   git pull http://github.com/someone/someproject.git
4. enter your project folder

   $ cd someproject
5. run this node command

   $ node index.js
6. access the server (you can use the ip ex: http://203.120.100.113:8000)
7. ???
8. profit

   node index.js ??? profit

Comment: I'm trying to upload to ftp to be published in a website folder. Should I really do that?

Comment: You need to provide more information on the server. Node server is not just server its an echo system and you create the server by using the server module. Express.js makes it easy for you. So provide more information on your hosting setup and if some daemon process takes care of kicking up the node server like elastic beanstalk on aws.

Comment: I'm using hostgator.

Answer (score 0):

First change your port to 22 since it's the default port used for making ftp requests. Next you'll have to port forward it on your router to your computer that's running the server. It's just telling your router that requests on port 22 should reach a particular computer on your local network. You can easily do that on your router. You can access then access your ftp server by using your public ip address , you can google search for your public ip address and then use it like this,
ftp://xx.xx.xx.xx where xx.xx.xx.xx is your public ip address.